# Retrieving data in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

My database:

```
notes                 notebooks             users
---------             ---------             ------
notes_id              book_id               user_id
book_id               book_name             user_name
user_id                                     user_pass
```

First field of each table is primary key.
In View index of User, I want to list all Notebook.book_name. How to do that use CakePHP? Thank you!
P/s: I am using CakePHP 2.5.6.

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html**

Comment: Thanks, but I know that.

Comment: Then you should be able to formulate a proper problem description.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to list all notebook on user index page, means you'll do the logic of retrieving the data on action index() of UserController.

Here is how you do it

```
class UserController extends AppController{
   public function index(){
       $notebooks = $this->Notebook->find('all');
       $this->set('notebooks',$notebooks);
   }
}
```

Then in your app/View/User/index.ctp , iterate to show all notebooks

```
<?php
     foreach($notebooks as $notebook):
        echo $notebook['Notebook']['notebook_name'];
     endforeach;
?>
```

You can read more on CakePHP find method here : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html